# TextWatcher Isn't WorkingI'm using Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I don't get any errors when running the code but the addTextChangedListener isn't running when I execute it. I am trying to have the continue button disabled until the user input text. When run, the continue is still enabled. Here is my code

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText



class First_Name_Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var editFirstNameText: EditText
    lateinit var btnOpenActivity: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_name)


        editFirstNameText = findViewById(R.id.first_name_edit_text)
        btnOpenActivity = findViewById(R.id.first_name_continue_btn)


        editFirstNameText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

            }
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                btnOpenActivity.isEnabled=true
            }
        }
        btnOpenActivity.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Last_Name_Activity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left)

        }

    }
        override fun finish() {
        super.finish()
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)

        }
}
```

Comment: Where do you disable the button, the listener seems to enable it?

Comment: post your xml code if you have disabled the button from xml

Comment: Thanks everyone, I had to disable the button first in order to make the addTextChangedListener work.

Answer (score 0):

`onTextChanged()` may be called even when the `CharSequence` is empty or null. There is a very simple fix to your problem, a null and non-empty check :

```
override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    if(s != null && s.isNotEmpty()){
       btnOpenActivity.isEnabled=true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned ***"When run, the continue is still enabled"***. Have you set the button to be disabled in the XML or through code (in the `onCreate` method) to be disabled when the app runs? After that, you can do:

```
override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    btnOpenActivity.isEnabled = s?.isNotBlank() == true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for empty text in edittext,

```
override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
       btnOpenActivity.isEnabled=true
    } else {
       btnOpenActivity.isEnabled=false
    }
}
```

Or

```
override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
     if (!editFirstNameText.text.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
         btnOpenActivity.isEnabled=true
     } else {
         btnOpenActivity.isEnabled=false
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First check edittext is empty or not then
Write below code inside textwatcher

```
If(s?.isEmpty()){
    btnOpenActivity.isEnabled

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code like this

```
editFirstNameText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

    }
    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            //btnOpenActivity.isEnabled==true
            //Change this line to line bellow
            btnOpenActivity.isEnabled==!s.toString().isEmpty()

    }
 })//you miss this bracket ')' in your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this will works for you...

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_text_watcher)
    btnOpenActivity.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {  })

    editFirstNameText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

            if (s != null) {
                btnOpenActivity.isEnabled = s.trim().isNotEmpty()
            }

        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

        }
    })



}
```

happy_coding :)